# Google Analytics scheduled email reports: naming multiple attachments

Tags: google-analytics

I have a custom report set up with multiple tabs. When scheduling an email, it seems like you can only have the current "view" added as an attachment (i.e. no option to email the entire report) - so I go through individual report tabs and [add reports to an existing schedule](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en).

The problem I'm having is naming the attachments - they all end up being named the same after the "parent" custom report. How can I work around this, or better yet, generate one PDF file from the multitab report?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to have multiple tabs sent through one report without doing what you've suggested. So, you have a few options:

1) Breakout each tab into its own custom report and add them all to your scheduled email. This way you'll have control over the name of the report.

2) Use Google Analytics Core Reporting API through this handy script that one of the leads at Google put together to export data from GA to Google Spreadsheets:

[Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic)

Sure it will require some time to build out, but it's time well spent.